# show previously hacked passwords with John The Ripper

Tags: password-cracking, john-the-ripper

I tried to crack my windows passwords on the SAM file with john the ripper, it worked just fine, and it shows me the password. But when i try to hack the same file again, john just tells me :

```
Loaded 4 password hashes with no different salts (LM [DES 128/128 SSE2-16])
No password hashes left to crack (see FAQ)
```

How can i see my previously hacked passwords ??!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To see previously cracked passwords, from the file `hashed_passwords.txt` that contains hashed passwords, we use this command :

```
john --show hashed_passwords.txt
```